# Approximate solution for high order polynomial (order 12)

Tags: polynomials, approximation, approximation-theory

I'm trying to get an approximation value of y by x from the following equation

$\ x = $$\sum_{i=1}^{12} y^i$

The current suggestion is to take y=1+z and z tending to zero or y tending to 1

any ideas

Comment: If $y$ tends to $1$, then $x$ will tend to $12$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mechanized in Maple. Here is an example.

```
sol := allvalues(solve(x = add(y^i, i = 1 .. 12), y)):series(sol[2], x = 0, 2);
```

> $$ 1/2\sqrt {2+2i\sqrt {3}}+$$
>   $$512x\times
>  $$
>   $$ \left( 3\, \left( 2+2\,i\sqrt {3} \right) ^{11/2}-3072\,i\sqrt {3}+10
> \, \left( 2+2\,i\sqrt {3} \right) ^{9/2}-3072+32\, \left( 2+2\,i\sqrt 
> {3} \right) ^{7/2}+96\, \left( 2+2\,i\sqrt {3} \right) ^{5/2}+256\,
>  \left( 2+2\,i\sqrt {3} \right) ^{3/2}+512\,\sqrt {2+2\,i\sqrt {3}}
>  \right) ^{-1}+
>  $$
>   $$O(x^2) $$

Comment: That is great, Thanks a lot!